# Select a defined range of slides through textboxes

Tags: vba, range, powerpoint

I want to select a range of slides in Powerpoint by vba. For Excel you simply write

> Range("A1:A100")

I want to select from slide number 5 to 10, how do I code that? My code just selects two slides:

> ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(5,10)).Select

Comment: Put all the slide numbers in the array. Array(5,6,7,8,9,10).  This may help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slides-range-method-powerpoint

Comment: I can't do that, because the first and last number are dynamic. I set them in two textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. This will depend on which type of Text box you are using. I am assuming standard textbox you select which is a shape. I am using some test textboxes which you would need to adjust to suit your needs.

You call the sub SelectSlides to generate the array of slides numbers for the slides to select between the two text box numbers.

You use the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slides-range-method-powerpoint) method to return any number of shapes or slides.
To specify an array of integers or strings for Index, you can use the Array function or, I believe, pass an array into the Range.

I will be upfront, whilst this worked once, powerpoint the crashed and since then the code has selected only the last item.

However, you can assign `ppt.Slides.Range(slidesArray)` to a `Slides` object and work with that e.g.

```
Dim slidesObject As Slides

Set slidesObject = ppt.Slides.Range(slidesArray)
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectSlideArray()

    Dim ppt As Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim textBox1 As Shape
    Dim textBox2 As Shape

    Set ppt = ActivePresentation
    Set sld = ppt.Slides(1) ' slide with text boxes in 
    Set textBox1 = sld.Shapes("TextBox 3") 'change as required
    Set textBox2 = sld.Shapes("TextBox 4") 'change as required

    textBox1.TextFrame.TextRange = 5 ' you can say TextRange.Text but .Text is defaut
    textBox2.TextFrame.TextRange = 10

    Dim startSlideNumber As Integer
    Dim endSlideNumber As Integer

    startSlideNumber = Int(textBox1.TextFrame.TextRange)
    endSlideNumber = Int(textBox2.TextFrame.TextRange)

    SelectSlides ppt, startSlideNumber, endSlideNumber

    'PrintShapeNames sld

End Sub

Public Sub SelectSlides(ByVal ppt As Presentation, ByVal startSlideNumber As Long, ByVal endSlideNumber As Long)

    Dim outputSlideNumber As Long

    outputSlideNumber = startSlideNumber

    If ppt.Slides.Count < endSlideNumber Then
        MsgBox "You don't have enough slides in the presentation!"
        End
    ElseIf endSlideNumber < startSlideNumber Then
        MsgBox "End slide is before start slide!"
        End
    Else
       Dim slidesArray()
       ReDim slidesArray(0 To endSlideNumber - startSlideNumber)
       Dim currentSlide As Long

       For currentSlide = LBound(slidesArray) To UBound(slidesArray)

           slidesArray(currentSlide) = outputSlideNumber
           outputSlideNumber = outputSlideNumber + 1

       Next currentSlide

    End If

    ppt.Slides.Range(slidesArray).Select

End Sub

Private Sub PrintShapeNames(ByVal sld As Slide)

    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name  
    Next shp

End Sub
```